# How to count the number of devices in the end path structure of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: path, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How can I count the number of devices under a certain path of Apache IoTDB? For example path like `root.test.dz01.sy01.zb01.jd01`, `root.test.dz01.sy01.zb01.jd02`, `root.test.dz01.sy01.zb01.jd03`, etc. How should I write the statement to count the number of `jd` level devices under `root.dz01.sy01.zb01`?

Answer (score 0):

Apache IoTDB is able to use `COUNT NODES <PathPattern> LEVEL=<INTEGER>` to count the number of nodes at the given level in data structure considering a given pattern, so this can be used to query the number of devices with specific measurements. Try command like `COUNT NODES root.**.temperature LEVEL=3`.